# How to connect to an existing Electron app using Spectron

Tags: webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver, spectron

Is it possible to connect to an existing Electron application using Spectron? I am not particularly sure on how to go about implementing this..

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
import { Application } from 'spectron';
import electronPath from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

// but don't spawn new electron application
new Application({
  path: electronPath,
  args: [path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app')],
});
```

There are some documentation out there for using [debuggerAddress](https://github.com/electron/spectron) option in Spectron, but I'm not really sure on whether that is what I am looking for, since the arguments for debuggerAddress is url, like so: '127.0.0.1:1234'.

Comment: I am still not sure what you try to do. With connect, you mean you want to use an app that is  already running somewhere? Why is it bad to start the app anew in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled making this work for Electron 6, was able to in the end, here is a working repo (made changes on top of an older one)

https://github.com/florin05/electron-spectron-example

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have created Test Folder in the same directory and create spectron file in this file.

Json File Changes:

```
"scripts": {"test": "mocha"}
const app = new Application({path: electronPath,args:[path.join(__dirname,'..')],})

beforeEach(function () {return app.start()})

afterEach(function () {if (app && app.isRunning()) {return app.stop()}})
```